# How is resolved concurrency and locking in Cassandra memtable?

Tags: concurrency, cassandra

is Cassandra memtable "copy on write" updated row to provide MVCC?
In SStable (immutable) there is no problem but how is resolved concurrency in memtable?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no MVCC because there is no such thing as isolation levels in Cassandra.  The atom of work is a single column; if you want isolation across larger units than that, you'll need to use external locking like http://code.google.com/p/cages/

Comment: It should also be pointed out that there is generally a way to model your data (and possibly client behavior) so that isolation isn't necessary.